# IntelliSense for non-HTML markup when editing .ASPX files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, vxml

I'm currently evaluating tool options for Voice XML development. I'm currently seeing if existing web development tools will work, since the model is quite similar (markup sent to browser client, ECMAScript in the browser, pages on web servers, etc.). I know I can use aspx pages to generate non-html markup, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get the IntelliSense to work the same way it does if you were editing an XML file in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can add intelligence support for any kind of xml document by adding it's schema definition to XML\Schemas folder of VisualStudio.

if you are asking of combining VoiceXML and ASPX markups together in an .aspx files i think it would not be possible in that way. i think it requires a new ViewEngine (for example something like Razor is doing that by combining Razor-Markups & HTML)